# flutter enable event after releasing button

Tags: flutter

`$ flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.4, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale
    ko-KR)
    • Flutter version 2.0.4 at /Users/jeongjiheon/development/flutter
    • Framework revision b1395592de (5 days ago), 2021-04-01 14:25:01 -0700
    • Engine revision 2dce47073a
    • Dart version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/jeongjiheon/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 49.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.55.0)
    • VS Code at /Users/jeongjiheon/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.21.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.114

• No issues found!
```

## Explanation

1. There is a single button
2. The button is in `State A`, when being pressed down
3. The button does not trigger any other events while the pointer is being dragged across the screen.
4. The button is in `State B`, when the pointer is dismissed from the screen i.e. dragged over the screen or pointer not intact with the screen.

## What I have tried

- Using GestureDetector and created functions for methods `onTapDown` and `onTapUp`
- This is what I get

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following RangeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Value not in range: 0

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49  throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/js_string.dart 171:66           substring]
packages/safer/controllers/number_pad_controller.dart 37:31                   deleteInput
packages/flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart 991:14                            [_handleTap]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 182:24                          invokeCallback
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 607:48                                 handleTapUp
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 296:5                                  [_checkUp]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 267:7                                  acceptGesture
packages/flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart 157:12                               sweep
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 385:20                             handleEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 361:14                             dispatchEvent
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 278:11                            dispatchEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 316:7                              [_handlePointerEventImmediately]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 280:5                              handlePointerEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 238:7                              [_flushPointerEventQueue]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 221:32                             [_handlePointerDataPacket]
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 911:13                            invoke1
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 170:5                             invokeOnPointerDataPacket
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 128:39                                [_onPointerData]
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 553:18                                <fn>
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 506:21                                <fn>
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 214:16                                <fn>

Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer:
  TapGestureRecognizer#87a24
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: RangeError: Value not in range: 0
```

- However, it moves from `State A` to `State B`
- But when I move the pointer out of the button while intact with the button and then removing the pointer from the screen, the button does not change to `State B` and stays in `State A`

## Question

- I would like suggestions on what should be necessary to fix this problem
- Or any supplementary resources that I might find helpful to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I could make a way around this.

1. Set `onLongPress` method to `State A`
2. Set `onLongPressEnd` method to `State B`